# CMD recursively batch rename files matching a pattern

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

this is my first Q on here, please forgive my ignorance in case I miss on best practices. I've reviewed prior requests to similar tasks, but couldn't apply their solutions to the situation described below.

This is about a CMD batch script to rename certain files only in a DIR and its SUBDIRs. All files share the same pattern:
`FILENAME 0000.png`
where 0000 is an arbitrary four digit number. Thanks to prior solutions here, I do have a working code for one DIR, alas, adding `/r` didn't make it recursive.

Below is a code snippet from my current CMD .bat (Win10 x64), removing `/r` works fine when renaming files in just one DIR only:

```
:dir_files_rename
SETLOCAL
SET "Path=G:\to\dir"

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%f in ("%Path%\*.png") do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
   set "filename=%%~nf"
   echo %filename%
  ren "%%f" "!filename:~0,-5!%%~xf"
)
ENDLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
goto start
```

I don't have a method to identify and pass on exclusively files matching above pattern, because I can't come up such a method (doh!). Not elegant at all, because my code affects all files, but at least that's a start.

Cheers, BF

Comment: Instead of `FOR /R` use a `FOR /F` command that parses the output of the `DIR` command that is piped to the `FINDSTR` command. That way you can match your pattern. `FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b /s *.png ^|findstr /R /C:".*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.png$"') DO ...`

Comment: Thank you @Squashman. I've tried to insert my %Path% variable within the `DIR` command, and  within the `FINDSTR`, alas, neither worked. Where do I put the %Path%?

Comment: For starters **NEVER** overwrite the `SYSTEM` path variable.  If you want to name a variable as your path then use an underscore or something. `SET "_Path=G:\to\dir"`. I would not recommend trying to put your path variable into the `DIR` command.  Do a change directory before the `FOR` command. `cd /d "%_path%"`

Comment: If your question is answered then post it as answer below. You are allowed to post answers to your own questions. Then please delete your comment as that much code in a comment is unreadable.

Comment: Thanks again, @Squashman, did that. My question has now been fully answered.